# modified values for Struts 2 action variable in interceptor post processing not sustained

Tags: struts2, interceptor

I have a requirement for formatting some variables before going to action and reformat after action executed but before rendering.  I added a interceptor.  I format the action variable value before invoke method called and reformat after invoke method called.  Changes made before invoke method in interceptor are effective in Action execute method.  But the changes made for reformat on action variables after invoke method executed are not seen when the page rendered.  Will the framework not take the changes done in Action variables in interceptor's post processing section?  Please help.

Comment: Could you provide details of your use case? Generally the action can handle formatting concerns. Your issue is interesting.

Comment: Agreed, this looks like treating a symptom, rather than solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

By the time `invoke` returns control to the interceptor the result has been rendered.

You need to implement a `PreResultListener` as described in the [big yellow box on the "Writing Interceptors" doc page](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/writing-interceptors.html).

Comment: Wait, what? How can struts even know *which* of the results will be applied at all before the interceptors finish and return? What if for example, the action class returns succes, but my interceptor ditches that and returns something else instead? Or what if the result is dynamic like, the result ${myPage}.jsp where myPage is a string that is being set somewhere during the action/interceptor cycle?

Comment: @user1884155 Because that's how it works. There's a difference between returning a result and short-circuit the chain and returning the result of invocation.invoke().

Comment: I've read great deal of tutorials on struts2 and I'm absolutely baffled about this. Even the link you provided has a very quirky way of saying the following: "the result returned by an action class's action method is the result that will be used, and whatever the interceptors return afterwards is not accounted for". A side question then: what is the point of the string that is returned by the interceptor if it is seemingly discarded anyway?

Comment: @user1884155 ... But it's not just discarded-results from interceptors are how things like validation work. If you get as far as the action invocation then unless you have a pre-result listener the action determines the result. That's because of what I said-the response has been rendered by the time invocation.invoke() returns. That doesn't mean functionality can't live in interceptors after invoke()-consider an open-session-in-view implementation.