# Struts2 timing on filling in <s:property> tags in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I have a simple struts2 web application with one action class and one interceptor. The action class has a getter method `getTitle()` which fetches a string from the session. The interceptor is on the bottom of the default stack so it executes lastly and first after the invocation. It is built in such a way that it can modify the title that is in the session BEFORE action invocation and AFTER invocation. The resulting JSP page then shows this title.

I thought the following logic would apply:

> 1. interceptor logic before invocation runs
> 2. action class logic runs
> 3. interceptor logic after invocation runs
> 4. struts knows the result and gets the `.jsp` page in the result
> 5. struts fills in the `<:s>` tags in `.jsp` and call `getTitle()` from the action class.

However this didn't work. The resulting JSP always showed the title as it was before step 3 was executed. I added some simple logging in my java code and it confirmed my suspicion. This was the order of execution:

> 1. log: interceptor logic before invocation runs
> 2. log: action class logic runs
> 3. log: `getTitle()` method from action class runs
> 4. log: interceptor logic after invocation runs

So somehow step 6 became step 3. Why is this and how can I add logic in my interceptor AFTER action invocation to alter the title?

Comment: Use session map to get the title or repopulate it from where the logic is implied.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14699541/438992, http://stackoverflow.com/a/23439297/438992, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nutshell: implement `PreResultListener` to have stuff happen before rendering, but after invocation.

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/writing-interceptors.html

I don't know what `title` is, but I'm having a hard time understanding why anything relating to something like a page title, or a book title from a domain object, or much else would need to:

1. Be retrieved by an action, or
2. Be changed by an interceptor

Comment: The title was just dummy, of ocurse i'm dealing with more complex data. Thanks for the info, I did not know the following: "the result returned by an action class's action method is the result that will be used, and whatever the interceptors return afterwards is not accounted for".